# Tkinter python 3.8 comboboxes in loop. How correct wrong choice while appending to list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, combobox, append

I´ve created a loop of comboboxes and I'm appending the choices I make to a list. There are 3 comboboxes. The list must have 3 corresponding elements. The problem is that if I change my mind while choosing and replace the option, the list (of course) increases in size.
In this code I have 3 options: 'The One!', 'more or less','the bad'. I want to change the options during selection, but keeping the list always with 3 unique elements corresponding to number of combobox. I've tought about using set but didn't work because the actual loop is large.

I need the list with just the len of comboboxes with result corresponding to the last choices, independently of the number of choice changes I've done.

Thank you for any help.

```
from tkinter import  ttk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Button

root = Tk()
my_heroes = ['Zidane', 'Ronaldo', 'Messi']
position = ['The One!', 'more or less','the bad']
result =[]

def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    result.append(cmb.get())
    print(result)
    
  
for index, heroe in enumerate(my_heroes):
    var = StringVar()
    bestPlayers = ttk.Combobox(root,values=position, textvariable=var, state="readonly")
    bestPlayers.grid(row=0 + index, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    
    label = Label(root, text = heroe)
    label.grid(row=0 + index, column=0,padx=(15,25))

    bestPlayers.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, cmb=var:get_combo_choice(event, cmb))

    
    button = Button(root, text ="get list of choices", command = callback)
    button.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=(15,25))

root.mainloop()
```

The print grows to three, ok, but then continues...
I need to keep size of list = combobox len and freely update the values getting the last 3 choices at the end.

['The One!']

['The One!', 'more or less']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad', 'The One!']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad', 'The One!', 'more or less']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad', 'The One!', 'more or less', 'The One!']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad', 'The One!', 'more or less', 'The One!', 'more or less']

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad', 'The One!', 'more or less', 'The One!', 'more or less', 'more or less']

Answer (score 1):

You can limit list length by usng list slice.

```py
def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    global result
    result.append(cmb.get())
    # limit list len to 3 using ~2
    result = result[~2:]
    print(result)
```

In order to control `result` columns a few things need to be added to your code.

```py
result =[None, None, None]
best = []

# Here's the alternative 
def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    i = best.index(event.widget)
    result[i] = cmb.get()
    print(result)
```

Inside the for\loop insert `best.append(bestPlayers)`

Comment: Interesting, but, lets suppose I change  first combobox 3 or more times and select combobox 2 and 3 just one time each. The list will show just the last three chooses from first combobox and not  what I need: last selection of combobox1, first  selection of combo 2 and 3. How to solve this main problem?

Comment: That's a little bit more complicated but I'll modify my answer to include alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Derek
I updated my code with your answer. It works like a charm!! You teached me a lot, big thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  ttk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Button

root = Tk()
my_heroes = ['Zidane', 'Ronaldo', 'Messi']
position = ['The One!', 'more or less','the bad']
# result =[]

# def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
#     result.append(cmb.get())
#     print(result)
result =[None, None, None]
best = []

# Here's the alternative 
def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):
    i = best.index(event.widget)
    result[i] = cmb.get()
    print(result)    
  
for index, heroe in enumerate(my_heroes):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    bestPlayers = ttk.Combobox(root,values=position, textvariable=var, state="readonly")
    best.append(bestPlayers)
    bestPlayers.grid(row=0 + index, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    
    label = tk.Label(root, text = heroe)
    label.grid(row=0 + index, column=0,padx=(15,25))

    bestPlayers.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, cmb=var:get_combo_choice(event, cmb))

    
    button = tk.Button(root, text ="get list of choices", command = get_combo_choice)
    button.grid(row=4, column=0,padx=(15,25))

root.mainloop()
```

code results in :

['The One!', None, None]

['The One!', None, None]

['The One!', None, None]

['The One!', 'more or less', None]

['The One!', 'more or less', 'the bad']

Answer (score 0):

One last question:
in: def get_combo_choice(event, cmb):

I understand event(choice--> ex:"the one"),

cbm (--> the variable) and that results uses the index to get choice from best(list),

what I dont understand is why I can't use i = best.index() if best is a list we already know. What is (event.widget) and what it is doing there? By the way your code fits all my needs.

Comment: `event.widget` is a reference to the object in `object.bind(` which in this case is a `Combobox`, then `i = best.index(` searches the `best` list and returns the integer index for `event.widget` (0, 1 or 2).

Comment: Mr Derek,

thanks for the Enlightenment !!